# SDCARD files permissions on Android using NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to open file on proprietry SDCARD usign standard method:
hFile= open(filePath, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECT);

Sdcard is our proprietry card which was created using external tool, and when card is inserted ingo Android phone, the permission of file is:
----rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw    65536 2011-11-06 12:13 IMSP
I guess Android decides on this permission.
Anyway, file can't be open for writing
Is any way to change the android application userid or groupid?

Regard, Costa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is simple, just add:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

To the manifest file

Answer (score 0):

you get the path to the File used in the File() by calling a system method

not all files (extern storage) go to where they say the are but if you fiddle with it like File.list() or something on what the Android gives you for external storage prob can figure it out

Comment: There is no problem with file path, only with permisttions